# Read a charlist in non utf-8 encoding

Tags: string, encoding, character-encoding, elixir

Assume we get a *`charlist`* from the foreign source, and it basically represents a string in some legacy 1-byte encoding like `ISO-8859-2`. There is a [`CodepageX`](https://github.com/tallakt/codepagex) package, that simplifies the conversions between different encodings, but it’s [`to_string`](https://github.com/tallakt/codepagex/blob/master/lib/codepagex.ex#L275) function expects a [`binary`] as an input.

All the standard library functions assume `Latin1` aka `ISO-8859-1` input encoding when transforming to `utf8` (like `to_string`, `IO.chardata_to_string`, `"#{}"` etc.)

What I came up with is:

```
input
  |> to_string
  |> Codepagex.from_string!(:iso_8859_1)
  |> Codepagex.to_string!(:iso_8859_2) # target encoding
```

which is a bit ugly.

Is there any robust and handy built-in/idiomatic elixir way to get a *`string`* out of *`charlist`* in known encoding?

Comment: Is this better: `input |> :erlang.list_to_binary |> Codepagex.to_string!(:iso_8859_2)`? Seems to be working correctly: `[224] |> :erlang.list_to_binary |> Codepagex.to_string!(:iso_8859_2) #=> "ŕ"`.

Comment: @Dogbert yes, it’s definitely more clear, since it does not involve suspicious  and superfluous `to_string |> Codepagex.from_string!(:iso_8859_1)` conversion and yes, it works correctly. Please post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`to_string` on a List of integers in Elixir treats the integers as Unicode codepoints (`to_string [960] #=> "π"`) while you want to treat each integer as a byte. In Erlang, this can be done using `list_to_binary`. I couldn't find any wrapper for this in Elixir's builtin modules but you can always call `:erlang.list_to_binary`:

```
iex(1)> [224] |> :erlang.list_to_binary
<<224>>
iex(2)> inspect ([224] |> to_string), binaries: :as_binaries
"<<195, 160>>"
iex(3)> [224] |> :erlang.list_to_binary |> Codepagex.to_string!(:iso_8859_1)
"à"
iex(4)> [224] |> :erlang.list_to_binary |> Codepagex.to_string!(:iso_8859_2)
"ŕ"
```